# Swift forEach with assignment inside the block

Tags: swift, struct, foreach, copy-on-write

Let's say I have this

```
var array = [1,2,3]

array.forEach {
    array.append(17)
    print($0)
}
```

It will not loop forever, instead it will print 1, 2 and 3 and afterwards the array has 6 elements: [1,2,3,17,17,17]

How can this be understood?

the array inside the block is a copy of the array the moment i call `.append(17)`, right? And then after the loop it's assigned to the array var? Or is the copy made before hand?

which is actually what is going on?

This:

```
var array = [1,2,3]
var arrayCopy: [Int]

array.forEach {
    arrayCopy.append(17)
    print($0)
}

array = arrayCopy
```

or this:

```
var array = [1,2,3]
var arrayCopy = array

arrayCopy.forEach {
    array.append(17)
    print($0)
}
```

Or something else?

Comment: "It will not loop forever" -- that's a very good thing.

Answer (score 0):

Intersting observation. Second answer looks more accurate when u create a forEach a copy of current array is created and looped through it's elements.

```
var array = [1,2,3]
var arrayCopy = array

arrayCopy.forEach {
    array.append(17)
    print($0)
}
```

If u run following code in playground u will get output showing element added to main array for each cycle of the loop

```
var array = [1,2,3]

array.forEach {_ in
    array.append(17)
    print(array)
}


//You will get following output 
//[1, 2, 3, 17]
//[1, 2, 3, 17, 17]
//[1, 2, 3, 17, 17, 17]
```

Answer (score 0):

The first one is accurate and works fine but you have to initialize your `arrayCopy` as an empty array like below:

```
var array = [1,2,3]
var arrayCopy: [Int] = []

array.forEach {
    arrayCopy.append(17)
    print($0)
}

array = arrayCopy
```

Which will give you the same output as you already added the output into your array but this Valid only if you wanna make a copy and put it in your original array.

Comment: No sorry I don't want to write it, I meant that I want to understand what is going on under the hood.